# Generate second number based on first random number

Tags: javascript, numbers

I wish to use Javascript to generate a random number between 1 and 2 inclusive.

Easy enough, I think -- something like?

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
```

But then I want to generate a second number, which if the first result is 1, is 2; and if the first result is 2, is 1.

(I hope the punctuation is clear.)

Update — random *integers*, I should have said (i.e. 1 or 2 only).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do so eloquently just by subtracting the first value from 3:

```
var first = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
var second = 3 - first;
```

Comment: Even more concise: `var second = 3 - first;`

Comment: @Xufox much appreciated, whoops

Comment: Funny how easy this is to miss

Comment: The approach to getting the second number is clever, but not scalable. Sometimes clever is not the way to go.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Good to know. I see your answer involves ternary operator to find the second number, is that more scalable?

Comment: @snapjs Well my approach will scale with some adjustment but your approach may not because if the second number criteria changes, `if/then` logic will most likely still apply, but mathematical calculation may not.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);  // Get 1 or 2
console.log("Random was: " + result);              // Test
var result2 = result === 1 ? 2 : 1;                // Ternary to get 2 or 1 based on first #
console.log("Answer is: " + result2);              // Test
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to generate the second number, given 1 you get 2 and given 2 you get 1.

You can use this for that:

```
num2 = num1 % 2 + 1
```

This uses the modulo operator which returns the remainder of integer division. i.e.:

```
1 % 2 == 1  // 1 / 2 = 0r1
2 % 2 == 0  // 2 / 2 = 1r0
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var rest = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
var rest2 = rest === 1 ? 2 : 1;
console.log("Random " + rest);
console.log("Num: " + rest2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that this is the only scenario your scripting will handle, you can do it with a simple if statement or a ternary like so:

### `if` example

```
var firstRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
var secondRandomNumber;

if (firstRandomNumber === 1) {
  secondRandomNumber = 2;
} else {
  secondRandomNumber = 1;
}
```

### Ternary example

```
var firstRandomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
var secondRandomNumber = firstRandomNumber === 2 ? 1 : 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wish to use Javascript to generate a random number between 1 and 2
>   inclusive.

```
function getRandInteger(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(min + (1 + max - min) * Math.random());
}

var myRandomNumb = getRandInteger(1, 2);
```

**edit** for integers only

> But then I want to generate a second number, which if the first result
>   is 1, is 2; and if the first result is 2, is 1.

a simple `if` / ternary operator...

Comment: Sorry — I should have been more precise. I wish only for whole numbers — i.e. 1 or 2.

Comment: You took out the `Math.floor` which takes care of decimals.

Comment: @ScottMarcus integers were not specified

Comment: Yes, but the OP's code along with the description made that obvious.

Comment: no: `random number between 1 and 2 inclusive` doesn't make it obvious.. "inclusive"?